# CollapsingToolbar in NavDrawer stuck in expanded position on scroll

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

For some reason, my `CollapsingToolbar` (within a `NavigationDrawer`) never seems to move when I scroll the RecyclerView underneath it. Have I missed something simple? How can I get it unstuck so the text positions itself next to the hamburger icon on scroll?

**DrawerLayout**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/myDrawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_md"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/masterToolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/master_container"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <include layout="@layout/layout_collapsingtoolbar" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/master_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/masterToolbar" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <!-- Container for contents of drawer -->
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/my_navview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_navdrawer" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Toolbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/myAppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/myCollapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `CoordinatorLayout` and it will work :)

To add a collapsing toolbar to your layout, place the 
CollapsingToolbarLayout inside an AppBarLayout. Then, add a Toolbar and any other views as a child to the CollapsingToolbarLayout.

**Make sure that the entire view structure is inside a CoordinatorLayout to take advantage of CollapsingToolbarLayout’s scrolling and features.**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_offset_start"
    app:expandedTitleMarginTop="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_offset_top"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_image_offset_top"
      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
      app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"/>

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/AppBar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_collapsed_height"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Reference](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Comment: Where did you get `@dimen/shrine_toolbar_offset_start` and `@dimen/shrine_toolbar_offset_top` from?

Comment: See the Reference link https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: They appear to be `dimen` files but there's no link to view or doewnload them.

Comment: Please be aware that a `RecyclerView` is underneath the collapsing toolbar hence this sounds complicated.

Comment: Wrap `CoordinatorLayout` then try what happens?

Comment: `RecyclerView` overlaps the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. See my updated XML codes. The `Toolbar` doesn't need to be in a `CoordinatorLayout`. I think the `ConstraintLayout` is making things complicated but it needs to be there.

Comment: Use `CoordinatorLayout` in your included file.

Comment: Added it but the `Toolbar` still won't collapse. If there isn't a proper working solution then I'll go back to the normal `Toolbar` because I need a marquee added to it anyway. See my updated `Toolbar` layout.

Comment: I have tried your code on my side it won't work because of drawer although is working without it :(

Comment: Ok, I think that's the problem. I'll have to go back to the normal `Toolbar`. Shame, because I hate having to stretch my thumb to reach the top item in my `RecyclerView`.